# Setting a compiled view (RazorGenerator) as a layout using an ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorgenerator

I created a layout view in a separate project (let's call it Shared) from the main MVC project (let's call it Main) and compiled that view using RazorGenerator. When I use the layout in any MVC page in Main it works fine:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

However, when I set the layout using an ActionFilter this way:

```
public class LayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        viewResult.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

And simply use it in the controller in Main like this:

```
[Layout]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

I'd really like to use an ActionFilter built into the Shared project so that I can just use it in any controller in the Main project (or any others).

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: @jamiedanq It is there. Like I said, when I use the Layout = "..." directly from the Index view it works. When I remove that line and use the ActionFilter instead I get the error.

Comment: Missed that part my wrong

Comment: Does the LayoutAttribute class reside in the same project as the `Layout`

Comment: @jamiedanq Yes. Although I've tried having the class as part of the Main project and I still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action from this:

```
public class LayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute

    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
            var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            viewResult.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
    }
```

To this one below:

```
public class LayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
             viewResult.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
         }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Still the same error. For what its worth, I had that conditional in the original implementation, but removed it from the stripped down version I'm trying to use to pinpoint the cause of the error.

Comment: Debug your application and set a breakpoint see whether it ends with true or false on if?

Comment: and would you please set the `ActionResult` method to return index like `return View("index") just to check whether that works or not

Comment: The ViewResult exists, so that's not the problem. Using an explicit view name like you suggested doesn't help either. I doubt the problem is in the ActionFilter, since if I use a local layout file it works fine. The problem is probably in the way the RazorGenerator view engine works I'm guessing.

Comment: Don't you think it could routing problem? is everything fine in your `RouteConfig.cs` file

Comment: Can't think of why that would be the problem. Since switching to setting the layout explicitly in the view works. It just stops working once we move that code (with the exact same path) to the ActionFilter.